# How to configuring NTL library in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ntl

I am trying to configure NTL library in my first Visual Studio 2010 project. I am following the instructions from: http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-win.html

I created a new Win32 project, named `ntl`.

Then, from `Project` -> `Add Existing Items` and selected all the files in the `src` file NTL library folder.

Then, I clicked in `Project` -> `Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Additional Include Directories` and I selected the `include` directory in the `NTL` library folder.

Finally, I tried to `Build`-> `Build ntl` but I am getting error says (for every file in the src):

```
c:\program files\winntl-5_5_2\src\ctools.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'NTL/ctools.h': No such file or directory
1>  Generating Code...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, follow this help step by step [Compiling NTL.](http://shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-win.html)

You must be doing something wrong, follow the instructions step by step it will work.
Save NTL in a path like it : C:\Library\WinNTL-5_5_2, and follow instructions of site.

Answer (score 0):

you probably don't need the answer for this question, but maybe for others who want to do it.

In Visual Studio (2010):

1. 'File' -> 'New' -> 'Project...' (or Ctrl + Shift + N)
2. Choose 'Win32 Project' (located under 'Installed Templates' -> 'Visual C++'), I named it NTLlib, click 'Ok'
3. Click 'Next >', Application type: 'Static library', in Additional options: uncheck 'Precompiled header', click 'Finish'
4. Right-click on created project in Solution Explorer 'Add' -> 'New Item...', (or Ctrl + Shift + A) choose C++ File (.cpp) name it and click 'Add' (it is necessary to set the C/C++ settings)
5. Download the latest [NTL library](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/download.html), extract it in your project
6. Right-click on your project go to Properties (or Alt + Enter) in 'Configuration Properties' -> 'C/C++', click on 'Additional Include Directories' from Dropdown menu choose edit -> 'New Line' (yellow Folder) -> set path to the downloaded NTL library **include** folder (no folder in include folder), click 'OK'
7. Right-click on your project in Solution Explorer 'Add' -> 'Existing item...' (or Shift + Alt + a), and select all files from downloaded NTL library in **src directory** click 'Add'
8. After loading all files at bottom left print VS ready, now click 'Build' -> 'Build NTLlib' and wait for 'Build: 1 succeeded'. Static library is created in Debug/Release folder.

For using the created library in another project just follow step 6., and set path to the created library folder: Right-Click on project -> 'Properties' -> 'Configuration Properties' -> 'VC++ Directories' -> 'Library Directories'/